# How to stop android device from corrupting pictures

Tags: gallery, images

When I take pictures with my device (Techno Phantom N9 running Android 4.2) the thumbnails and the images get corrupt. Hence I cant even send it to anybody, but on my device I can see some of the pictures even if the thumnail does not show.

[image: Imgur]
<sup>an image of what it looks like (click for larger variant)</sup>

I use the default camera app.

What could be the problem, and how could it be solved?

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're asking. Could you please [edit] your question and include some more details, e.g. Android version running, which camera apps you've tried (and whether it happens with all of them)? Thanks!

Comment: Edited my Question to include those. Simply put i on my camera, take a picture, view the picture and its fine. When i open gallery this is what it looks like. Thanks.

Comment: Multiple ideas to try out: 1) Have you tried a different camera app? 2) Have you tried a different storage (internal vs. external SDCard)? 3) If you're currently using the external SDCard, have you tried a different card (maybe the card is corrupted/malfunctioning)?

Comment: Hey thanks @Izzy it think the problem is the sdcard bcos i removed it and took some pictures which were stored in the internal storage and the was no problem. Do u have any suggestions of good sdcard i am currently using scandisk.

Comment: *LOL* (sorry). You certainly mean SANdisk (SCANdisk is a program to scan disks for corruptions). No recommendation here, as it very much depends (on the combination with the device, and on the budget). Take care to get at least class-6 (not below; for speed and battery consumption). // Please don't forget to let us know whether it solved the issue! I meanwhile will prepare an answer on it.

Answer (score 2):

There could be multiple culprits – and depending on which it is in your case, the solution is different:

1. **The camera app:** Try different camera apps, there are [plenty good choices](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=56) to select from. There might be a bug in the camera app, corrupting the file on saving it.
2. **Storage:** Photos can be stored to internal or external SDCard. Your external card could have problems (corruption, incompatibilities – not all combinations of brands/sizes and Android device work together equally well). Removing the external SDCard should force the camera app to save its photos on the internal SDCard. Check if the problem still persists. If not, your card might either be corrupted, or not working optimally with your device. You can check it for corruptions (e.g. using a card reader attached to your PC), or try with a different brand (make sure to buy only class-6 and above: better performance, less battery consumption).

Comment: please what is a class 6 sdcard and how can i identify one.

Comment: Your dealer will tell you. But [Wikipedia can as well](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SDCard#Speed_class_rating) :)

Comment: Hey @Izzy real lots of thanks. I am actually using a class 4 sdcard. That could be part of the problem but it wasn't always like that.

Comment: Class 4 should be OK for photos (saving just takes a little longer). In terms of speed, it might be critical for recording HD *video* (constant stream). As it makes not that big difference in price, I'd recommend using at least class-6 today. If you can effort it, buy two different cards from different manufacturers to try out interoperatibility. You should be able to return the "other" card afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me as well. I am guessing that one of the pictures was corrupt and that causes everything to be corrupt.

The way I fixed it was I connected my phone to my computer "as a media device" and copied all of the pictures (in `Internal Storage/DCIM/Camera`) to my computer to back them up. A few failed to copy (I'm guessing that these are the ones causing the problem). After I had them all backed up, I deleted the the `Internal Storage/DCIM/Camera` folder on my phone.

Then I took a new picture with my phone. It recreated the `Camera` folder and the picture was visible in the gallery as it should be.